# Do we have an app for Testing cellular/WiFi latency, http compression, etc

Tags: wifi, 3g, networking, cellular

I am looking for an app to give me status of my Cellular connection statistics such as:

- Download throughput
- Upload throughput
- Network latency.

It will be nice if can get the same statistics for my WiFi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Microsoft research launched a free app that can test both cellular and wifi. It is called "TestMyNet"

You can test network speed, ping , open/blocked portc etc

[Download](http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=a25ec139-fc33-4571-9425-cf031a3312bb)

[image: TestMyNet]